# How to remove HTML tags from ajax response using PHP?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I need to check from the database if email exists or not by using Ajax. I am getting a response, but coming with some HTML content. I have given below my code what I have followed.

**My Ajax code:**

```
var username_state = false;
var email_state = false;
$('#username').on('blur', function(){
    var username = $('#username').val();
    if (username == '') {
        username_state = false;
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'user_list.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'username_check' : 1,
            'user_name' : username,
        },
        success: function(response){
            $("html").html($("html", response).html());
            if (response == 'taken' ) {
                response.find(element).remove();
                alert('hi');
                username_state = false;
                $('#username').parent().removeClass();
                $('#username').parent().addClass("form_error");
                $('#username').siblings("span").text('Sorry... Username already taken');
            }
            else if (response == 'not_taken') {
                username_state = true;
                $('#username').parent().removeClass();
                $('#username').parent().addClass("form_success");
                $('#username').siblings("span").text('Username available');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**My php Code**

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'my_assesment');

if (isset($_POST['username_check'])) {
$username = $_POST['user_name'];
// echo  $username;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_information
            WHERE user_name='".$_POST["user_name"]."'";
//echo  $sql;
$results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    //$response = true;
    echo "taken";   
}else{
    $response = false;
  echo 'not_taken';
}
```

**This is am getting  response**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery -->
not_taken
```

Comment: Are you sending the AJAX request to the same page?

Comment: no I am sending to different page

Comment: How did you get here? You can't generally build an API based app only with frontend work and without a proper backend server. Whatever you manage to build will break randomly when anything changes on the server.

Comment: No, actually am working localhost Now am getting valid response, but it's not checking if condition . What I need to do?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the output you are receiving my guess is that the ajax request is being sent to the same page. If that is the case then initially wrap the entire username checking code within a suitable `if` test and ensure that any HTML buffer content is disposed of completely before sending the response to the ajax callback.

```
/*
    Test that the request is a POST request and that
    the variables you are expecting have been sent.
    
    As you are using data sent by the client you MUST
    take precautions to mitigate SQL injection attacks.
    
    Use a Prepared statement rather than directly embedding
    user supplied data in the SQL.
*/
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( 
    $_POST['username_check'],
    $_POST['user_name']
)){

    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'my_assesment');
    $sql='SELECT `user_name` FROM `user_information` WHERE `user_name`=?';
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['user_name']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $rows=$stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    
    $response=( $rows > 0 ) ? 'taken' : 'not_taken';
    
    # flush buffer to remove any other HTML / text content
    ob_clean();
    
    #exit completely from this logic branch
    exit( $response );
}
```

---

The test page I used to try to figure out the fault in the callback was exactly as follows. Essentially rather than respecting the checkbox to do a test and querying the db a random integer determines if the status is `taken` or `not_taken` simply to test the logic in the callback.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( 
        $_POST['username_check'],
        $_POST['user_name']
    )){
        /*
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'my_assesment');
        $sql='SELECT `user_name` FROM `user_information` WHERE `user_name`=?';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$_POST['user_name']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rows=$stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        */
        $rows=mt_rand(0,1);
        $response=( $rows > 0 ) ? 'taken' : 'not_taken';
        
        ob_clean();
        exit( $response );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>?Username Check Test Page</title>
        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <style>
            label{display:block;padding:1rem;}
            .form_success{background:rgba(0,255,0,0.25)!important;}
            .form_error{background:rgba(255,0,0,0.25)!important;)}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='usercheck'>
            <label>Username:<input type='text' id='username' name='user_name' value='geronimo' /></label>
            <label>Username Check:<input type='checkbox' name='username_check' value=1 /></label>
        </form>
        <script>
            var username_state = false;
            var email_state = false;
            
            $('#username').on('blur', function(){
            
                var username = $('#username').val();
                if (username == '') {
                    username_state = false;
                    return;
                }
                
                $.ajax({
                    url: location.href, //  'user_list.php' ~ same page here!
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        'username_check' : 1,
                        'user_name' : username,
                    },
                    success: function(response){
                        alert(response);
                        // no idea what this is doing
                        // $("html").html($("html", response).html());
                        if (response == 'taken' ) {
                            // this caused issues for me... no error as such but prevented further processing
                            // response.find(element).remove();
                            alert('hi - choose another username');
                            username_state = false;
                            $('#username').parent().removeClass();
                            $('#username').parent().addClass("form_error");
                            $('#username').siblings("span").text('Sorry... Username already taken');
                        }
                        else if (response == 'not_taken') {
                            username_state = true;
                            alert('ok - that user name is fine');
                            $('#username').parent().removeClass();
                            $('#username').parent().addClass("form_success");
                            $('#username').siblings("span").text('Username available');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }); 

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Now am getting a valid response, but it's not going to the  inside of if condition, what I need to do?

Comment: `"it's not going to the inside of if condition"` - do you mean within the AJAX callback?

Comment: Yes,  success: function(response){
  
      if (response == 'taken' ) 
   {//conditions not checking here }

Comment: But you can see a response in the console/network tab??

Comment: Yes, I c an able to see the response but it's not checking the conditions

Comment: I just created a basic test page and found that `response.find(element).remove();` was preventing the alert from appearing

Comment: Ok Thanks, can you give me the sample code? already I have tried this code but its not working this code. If you want I will send you my code. Today I have to complete this task.